# "Simultaneously" vs "concurrently"

Tags: differences, adverbs

Coming from a technical background I'm slightly confused. What is the difference between *simultaneously* and *concurrently*? How do we use these words?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I just looked these up in an online dictionary; this is what I found:

> **concurrently**: overlapping in duration
>
> **simultaneously**: at the same instant

Both of them mean "at the same time," and are almost interchangeable.

That said, if I had to point out a slight difference, I'd say that *concurrently* occurs over a longer time, and is a bit less synchronized than *simultaneously*.

For example:

> *The two processors were running concurrently, then they crashed simultaneously.*

In that example, I wouldn't swap the two words in question.

Comment: Good example..!

Answer (score 3):

In addition, concurrent has a few additional meanings, most of which amount to "in agreement," as in "two people working concurrently." That is to say, they're working towards the same goal. The other meaning of concurrent is related to geometry, where you might say two lines were concurrent: they're going to intersect at a common point.

EDIT:

[I don't have enough rep to comment beneath this yet, but I'd like to say I think you guys should stop commenting. I don't think you're adding anything anymore.]

Comment: In the geometry context, [here are 477 definitions](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22concurrent+lines%22+%22three+or+more%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), most of which say you need at least **three** lines intersecting at the same point in order to call them "concurrent". It would be pretty trivial to apply the term to just **two** lines, since they will always intersect unless they're [parallel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_(geometry))

Comment: @FumbleFingers: unless the two lines are in 3-dimensional space, and not in the same plane...

Comment: @J.R. I'm no mathematician, but Googling the two quoted strings **"concurrent lines" "3-d space"** gives only 42 results in total, many of which are about projecting 3-d lines onto a 2-d surface in order to manifest "concurrent lines". Which might even suggest that mathematicians avoid the term outside of plane geometry.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Your several contentions about concurrent lines are incorrect.  See for example [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_lines), which says "In projective geometry, in two dimensions concurrency is the dual of collinearity; in three dimensions, concurrency is the dual of coplanarity."

Comment: @jwpat7: I'm not making a "contention", I'm simply presenting the usage statistics from written sources. In such a restricted usage it doesn't really mean anything to quote one "authoritative" definition or another - all that matters is whether people actually *use* the terminology in particular ways. It would appear that, Wikipedia notwithstanding, they don't often use it in a 3-d context - **plus** there are those hundreds of written instances explicitly saying "concurrent" only applies with at least 3 lines. Their words, not mine.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Your opening statement ("two lines... will always intersect unless they're parallel") could be construed to imply that any two lines would always intersect, unless they were parallel. My gentle correction referred to geometry in general - not just to geometry where the term "concurrent" might be used.

Comment: @J.R.: I can hardly contest anything you say, I admit. But even though I'm *not* a mathematician, I think I'd be right in saying that *"plane geometry"* (as mentioned by way of a caveat in my second comment) only involves 2-d space. On top of which I can "sorta" deal with 2/3/4-d spacetime, but all I know about [Non-Euclidean geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Euclidean_geometry) is that it's *waaay* too hard for me!

Comment: @FumbleFingers: fair enough; but, when I wrote my comment, you hadn't posted your second comment yet ;^)  I was replying only to what you said in your first - nothing more.

Comment: @J.R.: Yeah, well I'd never even *heard* of "concurrent lines" before reading this answer. But I thought Aerovistae's definition made it seem a fairly pointless concept, and it just so happened I had a Google Books window open at the time. When I searched for *"concurrent lines"* I couldn't avoid noticing how often *"three or more"* was mentioned, which is all that prompted me to make the comment. I understand now how the *concept* might be useful, but I still don't see why they didn't call them *"convergent"* rather than *"concurrent"*.

Comment: @Aerovistae: +1 for the edit. I concur.  Most of that was way off-topic, and not concurrent with your post at all.